# Is there any way to tell if two strings share memory in Go?

Tags: string, go, equality

In Go, strings are stored internally as the C-struct:

```
struct String // This is C code (not Go)
{
  byte* str;
  int32 len;
};
```

Let's say I have the following variables:

```
a0 := "ap" // This is Go code
a1 := "ple"
b0 := "app"
b1 := "le"
a := a0 + a1
b := b0 + b1
c := "apple"
d := c
```

Then the following code:

```
fmt.Println("a == b = %t, &a == &b = %t", a == b, &a == &b)
fmt.Println("c == d = %t, &c == &d = %t", c == d, &c == &d)
```

outputs:

```
a == b = true, &a == &b = false
c == d = true, &c == &d = false
```

because `&a == &b` compares the addresses of the C-structs, while `a == b` compares the values of the strings.

Is there any way to test whether the strings themselves are stored in the same place (i.e. the `str` field in the C-struct has the same value), such that comparing `a` and `b` would most likely yield `false`, while comparing `c` and `d` would almost certainly yield `true`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use the reflect package and obtain the [String Headers](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StringHeader) of two `string` instances. Then you can compare *both* the `Data` and `Len` fields to compute whether the string backing arrays do overlap in memory.

Note: The `StringHeader` struct is an implementation detail, it's not mentioned by the language specs. Thus, any code doing things like discussed in the above paragraph is not really portable Go. IOW, I discourage to use such code outside of curiosity/research etc. From the docs:

> StringHeader is the runtime representation of a string. It cannot be used safely or portably and its representation may change in a later release. Moreover, the Data field is not sufficient to guarantee the data it references will not be garbage collected, so programs must keep a separate, correctly typed pointer to the underlying data.

EDIT:

Untested code to obtain a `*reflect.StringHeader` `hdr` from a `string` instance `str`:

```
hdr := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&str))
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you use it by just casting a `string` to a `StringHeader`?

Comment: @Matt: There's _no_ casting in Go. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Just another question, does all that casting have any overhead?